# How to use 'sed' in shell script to replace a line in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I've a file with a line contains special characters like % ^ #$ @#$. I tried to use sed tool to replace this line with pattern like this (name=value where value contains special characters).

```
sed -i 's|abc.defef.efefef.gege=%6p [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %c{1}@%L: %m%n|abc.defef.efefef.gege=%7p [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %d{1}@%X|g' FILE_NAME
```

How can I do this?

Example:

Name: `abc.defef.efefef.gege=,`

Value: `%6p [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %c{1}@%L: %m%n`

Need to replace value with new value: `%7p [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %d{1}@%X`

Comment: Please add a data example in terms of origin and required output.

Comment: Does it matter what the old value was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the special characters in the expression.

I've made a couple of changes:

- Escaped `.`, otherways it will match any characters.
- Added `^` so the key starts at the beginning of the line (otherwise you can match a postfix of another key).
- Removed the search for the original value (I assume it doesn't matter what it was), so you don't have to escape all the special characters there.
- Replaced the key in the replace part with `\1` to avoid duplication in the code.

`sed 's|^\(abc\.defef\.efefef\.gege=\).*|\1%7p [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %d{1}@%X|g'`